# Mostrar dados do cliente ao clicar nome

Tags: php, html

Preciso fazer com que me mostre em uma lista o nome dos clientes, e ao clicar em um botão ou no proprio nome do cliente, apareça os dados do mesmo, entretanto não tenho ideia de como prosseguir. tentei mostrar os dados em um pop-up, mas tambem sem sucesso.

Existem dois campos o nome a ação, a dificuldade em si esta no campo ação.

Segue codigo feito até o momento:

```
  <table id="data-table" class="table">           
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Nome</th>
           <th>Ação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php 

      $campanha = $_SESSION['campanha'];
      $query = sprintf("select int.start_time,int.nodename, int.dtmf,int.acao,cont.nome from ivr_interacao int , ivr_contatos cont where int.codigo = 798777 and cont.codigo = 798777");

    $result = Populator::ConsultaDB($query);

    $cont = 0;
    while ($resultado = pg_fetch_array($result) ) {
      $nome = $resultado['nome'];
      $acao = $resultado['acao'];
      $tempo = $resultado['start_time'];
      $cont = $cont + 1;
        echo '       
        ';
    }
     ?>

   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $nome; ?></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
```

Segue exemplo da pagina como esta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Feito uma edição na resposta que continha erro de sintaxe que ocasionava erro na edição de registro.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adaptar esse exemplo as suas necessidades.

```
<?php
//declaração das variaveis
$id = "";
$nome = "";
$tel = "";
$cel = "";
$email = "";

//conexão ao banco de dados
include_once('conectar.php');

if(!empty($_GET['acao'])){
   $acao = $_GET['acao'];

   if(($acao == "cadastrar")||($acao == "alterar")){
      $nome = $_POST['nome'];
      $tel = $_POST['tel'];
      $cel = $_POST['cel'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];

   }

   if($acao == "cadastrar"){
      $sql = ("insert into registro (nome, tel, cel, email) values ('$nome','$tel','$cel','$email')");
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   }else if($acao == "excluir"){
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $sql = ("delete from registro where id = '$id'");
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   }else if($acao == "alterar"){ 
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $sql = ("update registro set nome = '$nome',tel = '$tel',cel = '$cel',email = '$email' where id = '$id'");
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   }
}
?>

<!-- Biblioteca requerida -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<body>


<script>
/********************************************************************************
Função disparada ao clicar no link que abre o modal para edição (Modal Alterar)
valor e uma string com os dados cujo separador é um asteristico.
Com o metodo split separamos essa string para formar os valores a serem inseridos
nos campos do formulário do Modal Alterar
********************************************************************************/

function obterDadosModal(valor) {

   var retorno = valor.split("*");

   document.getElementById('id').value = retorno[0];   
   document.getElementById('nome').value = retorno[1];    
   document.getElementById('tel').value = retorno[2];
   document.getElementById('cel').value = retorno[3];  
   document.getElementById('email').value = retorno[4];  
}
</script>


<!--Modal Cadastrar-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalCadastrar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Adicione uma pessoa para que possa ter o seu registro salvo</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--- Modal com form para se fazer inclusão de registro -->
                <form class="form-group well" action="modal-edicao-registro.php?acao=cadastrar" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="span3" value="" required placeholder="Nome" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="tel" name="tel" class="span3" placeholder="Número de telefone" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;">
                        <input type="tel" name="cel" class="span3 pull-right" placeholder="Número de celular" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="span3" value="" required placeholder="Endereço email" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" name="adicionar" style="height: 35px">Adicionar registro</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--Modal Alterar-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalAlterar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Alteração de Registro</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--- Modal com form para se fazer a edição das informações -->
                <form class="form-group well" action="modal-edicao-registro.php?acao=alterar" method="POST">
                        ID <input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="">
                        Nome <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" class="span3" value="" required style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        Tel  <input id="tel" type="tel" name="tel" class="span3" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;">
                        Cel <input id="cel" type="tel" name="cel" class="span3" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        Email <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="span3" value="" required style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" name="editar" style="height: 35px">Alterar registro</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h2>Lista de pessoas registradas</h2><br>
    <form method="POST" action="modal-edicao-registro.php?acao=dados">
        <input type="text" name="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar pessoas" class="span4" style="margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;">
        <button type="submit" name="pesquisar" class="btn btn-large" style="height: 35px;">Pesquisar</button> 
        <a href="#myModalCadastrar"><button type="button" name="cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCadastrar">Cadastrar</button></a>
    </form>
    <table border="1px" bordercolor="gray" class="table table-stripped">
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>Telefone Fixo</td>
            <td>Celular</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Ação</td>
        </tr>
            <?php

                $consulta = ("select * from registro");

                if(!empty($_POST['pesquisa']))
                {
                    $pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa'];
                    $consulta = ("select * from registro where nome like '$pesquisa%'");
                }

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);

                while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dados['nome']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['tel']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['cel']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['email']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="modal-edicao-registro.php?acao=excluir&id=<?php echo $dados['id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir este registro?');"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="excluir">Excluir</button></a>

                <a href="#myModalAlterar" onclick="obterDadosModal('<?php echo $dados['id'];?>*<?php echo $dados['nome'];?>*<?php echo $dados['tel'];?>*<?php echo $dados['cel'];?>*<?php echo $dados['email'];?>')"><button type='button' id='alterar' name='alterar' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalAlterar'>Editar</button></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

> Em 09/07/2018 foi feita uma edição nesta linha
>   `<a href="#myModalAlterar" onclick="obterDadosModal('...$dados['email'];?><button...`
>
> falta de aspa e parentese `')` de fechamento da função `obterDadosModal` e fechamento da tag `a` `>`.
>
> Correto: `<a href="#myModalAlterar" onclick="obterDadosModal('......$dados['email'];?>')"><button...`

Comment: Opa, obrigado, vou estudar o codigo, obrigado!

Comment: OK, não esqueça de validar os dados, tanto no front quanto no  back end. Qualquer duvida deixe comentário aqui!!!